# Toggle "Unknown Sources" with Tasker

Tags: settings, tasker, unknown-sources

Is it possible to toggle the **Unknown Source** setting with Tasker? I couldn't find such a setting. I also tried the **Secure Settings** Plugin there is also no action for this.

What I want to achieve is to set this setting ***on*** when I start the Amazon AppStore and switch it ***off*** when I close it again.

Samsung Galaxy Note, Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in a totally automated fashion, as indicated by the accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850345/programmatically-change-the-permission-of-installing-apk-from-unknown-source-in). Basically, it's against the Android security model to allow `Unknown Sources` to be changed programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut.pro) can do the trick:

> AutoShortcut is a plugin for Tasker or Locale that allows you to run any of your installed apps' shortcuts.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a shortcut to toggle `Unknown Sources` for that to work? I'm not aware of any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

The device seems rooted because [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) is mentioned. I have v1.3.6 installed and it does allow toggling "Unknown sources".

All you have to do in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) is:

1. Create App context profile and choose **Amazon Appstore** or your favorite app.
2. To enable **Unknown sources** when **Appstore** is launched:

   - Create a task with action as **Plugin → Secure Settings**:

     - Under **Configuration**, go to **System+ Actions →Unknown Sources → On**, and save it.
   - Alternatively, if **Secure Settings** still doesn't have such option then create an action as **Code → Run Shell**, and type:

     - **Command**: `settings put global install_non_market_apps 1`
     - Check **Use Root**

     Explanation:

     - `settings` would update `settings.db` database file (part of `com.android.providers.settings`).
     - `global` is the table which holds the key (`install_non_market_apps`) responsible for toggling **Unknown Sources**.
3. To disable **Unknown sources** when **Appstore** is closed:

   More or less, once the **Appstore** is closed you'll come back to home screen (default Launcher). In that case:

   1. Create App context profile and choose your default launcher.
   2. Create a task with action as **Plugin → Secure Settings**:

      - Under **Configuration**, go to **System+ Actions →Unknown Sources → Off**, and save it.

      Or, alternatively, create an action as **Code → Run Shell**, and type:

      - **Command**: `settings put global install_non_market_apps 0`
      - Check **Use Root**

---

Your objective is now completed! Launch your **Appstore** and **Unknown sources** would get enabled. Come back to Launcher and **Unknown sources** would get disabled.

Comment: Ahh, forgot to mention that my solution is tested on Android 4.2.1 JB.